# Email not sending after upgrading magento version 2.2.4 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.3.1, mailchimp

Currently, using **Mandrill** for email flows and it's working fine before upgrade the Magento. My previous version is 2.2.4 and upgraded to 2.3.1.

After upgrade, the Magento emails are not getting flow.

When I am debugging the problem than I knew something like

[image]

I am getting an error like

> Invalid sender

`from_email` and `from_name` not getting is the main error.

Please help me, anybody, if any idea of this bug.

Thank you

Comment: @FaisalShikh thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above issue is resolved :

I have replaced the Mandrill module with a compatible 2.3.1 module.

https://github.com/ebizmarts/magento2-mandrill/tree/compatibility231

And added mandrill library using composer

```
composer require mandrill/mandrill
```

Now it's working like a champ.